# LaTex figure showing double brackets instead of single

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm having trouble getting the format of my Latex to work, so the code is attached as below, and I'm expecting each of the three subfigures would be labeled (a), (b), (c); but they're showing ((a)), ((b)), ((c)).

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\texttt{bcLeft=2},\,\texttt{bcRight=2},\\ \texttt{bcDown=0},\,\texttt{bcUp=0}]{
        \includegraphics[width=8cm]{Case_a/bc8_f4_NumericalSolution.png}\label{fig:Laplace_Dirichlet84}
    }
    \subfloat[\texttt{bcLeft=0},\,\texttt{bcRight=0},\\ \texttt{bcDown=2},\,\texttt{bcUp=2}]{
        \includegraphics[width=8cm]{Case_a/bc9_f4_NumericalSolution.png}
        \label{fig:Laplace_Dirichlet94}
    }
    \\
    \subfloat[\texttt{bcLeft=2},\,\texttt{bcRight=2},\\ \texttt{bcDown=2},\,\texttt{bcUp=2}]{
        \includegraphics[width=8cm]{Case_a/bc7_f4_NumericalSolution.png}
        \label{fig:Laplace_Dirichlet74}
    }
    \caption{Numerical solution for Laplace Equations with 3 constant cases under Dirichlet BC.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem. I have proper labelling (a), (b) and (c) for the subfigures. I probably comes from packages that you include. This is why I support samcarter comment. Without being ableto reproduce your problem, we have no way to help you.

Comment: @AlainMerigot I tried the same code on my previous project and it worked fine, and I worked on overleaf with the same packages for both... anything else i can try?

Comment: @Fffan: If you're working on Overleaf, you should be able to share a copy of your project. That way it would be easier to assess what's going on.

Answer (score -3):

I likewise had ((a)), ((b)), etc, in my subfigure labels, and removing `\usepackage{subfigure}` in the preamble resolved the issue: now (a), (b), etc.